# Complete separate activities within a CountDownTimer with result

Tags: android, android-activity, countdowntimer

Is there a way to call startActivityForResult() within a countdown timer for different activities? My current code:

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long theLong = 0;
        Integer i = (int) (long) theLong;
        i = (int) (Math.round(millisUntilFinished / 1000));  
        tv.append("Waiting..." + "\n");

        switch (i) {
           case 55:
            Intent intentBluetooth = new Intent(MainTestCycle.this, BluetoothActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intentBluetooth, Constants.BLUETOOTH_SUBACTIVITY);

            break;
           case 50:
            //Intent intentwifi = new Intent(MainTestCycle.this, WifiActivity.class);
            //startActivityForResult(intentwifi, Constants.WIFI_SUBACTIVITY);

            break;

        }            
    }

    public void onFinish() {

   }

 }.start();
```

However the onActivityResult() method is not called?

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure the countdowntimer is started?

Comment: The correct .start() is implemented I just havent included it in the snippet, sorry :)

Comment: and why you are casting the i two times: Integer i = (int) (long) theLong;? also, "theLong" makes no sense, You don´t need it...

Comment: Excuse my strange logic, still learning.  It was to convert to seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a little bit weird (sorry :)  ), but I will just try to give You a solution. So, what is Your intention to let the countdowntimer running after the activity has started? Because You gave 60 Seconds, but You want that this starts after 55 Seconds. If this timer should do nothing anymore after the activity is started, just give 55 seconds until countdown. I would do it like this:

```
             private class StartActivityTimer extends CountDownTimer {
  public StartActivityTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
   super(startTime, interval);
  }

   @Override
  public void onFinish() {

         Intent intent = new Intent(MainTestCycle.this, BluetoothActivity.class);
         startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.BLUETOOTH_SUBACTIVITY);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
   //do nothing
  }
   }
```

And then, make the timer Global:

```
      private StartActivityTimer timer = null;
```

initialize and start:

```
      timer = new StartActivityTimer(55000,1000);
      timer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I intend to call different activities on 5 second intervals until the end of the timer.  Some modification is needed to achieve this?

Comment: could You show me Your complete Timer? And, the @Override is missing in Your code, or is it just a paste/copy issue?

Comment: Apologies, please see my full implementation above ^^

Comment: ah, ok , I see what You want to do. But if one Activty has started, Your main activity will go to background, I don´t think that the second startActivity for Result will start 5 seconds after the first. Also, if will start, is this not a little bit confusing for the user if two different activities start every 5 seconds? Could You explain what the BluetoothActivity and the WifiActivity are there for?

Comment: Ahhh I see the issue here, the application completes tests for the hardware on the android device.  This will be automated mostly which is why I need a timer to keep the flow. Apologies for the complexity, is there another method I could use?